# How to animate from splash screen to main screen on Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, splash-screen, drawable

I followed the advice [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52) to setup my splash screen to be defined as a drawable and set as the theme for the launching Activity. However as expected the transition is a bit abrupt. Could someone suggest a way to animate the transition?

Answer (score 1):

The advice you've read is a very good way for creating splash screen, because we're avoiding blank screen on app initialization.

To create the activity/fragment transition I think there is no other way than creating a SplashActivity/SplashFragment and starting the transition after some delay or when necessary data is loaded.

However I haven't combined those two approaches together, so changing the theme and running the transition after. Maybe there is a way to combine those two, so we can end up with sweet spot, where we don't have blank screen on app start + we have transition.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Start an activity using an animation (Offical Document)](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) or [The Motion in Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion)